# Calendar overlay error message

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]

I have a calendar overlay with several team calendars on it. I noticed there is a message on top of the calendar stating "List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user [*****] <- this ID changes every time i reload the page. I went through every team calendar thinking it was a permissions issue, I can access every single team calendar with no issue. What i'm I missing? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is the overlay new?(Which version of SP are you using?)

Comment: This is an existing overlay. SP 2013 on-prem

Comment: None of the URL's have changed for the overlays?

Comment: They did once but I re-added the calendars and still showing the message. I also noticed the Id that shows on the message changes every time I refresh the page.

Comment: Did you resolve the Web URL's in the overlays settings?

Comment: Not yet but I'll try that tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: Have you created any custom content types that are being used in the list? It happens sometimes that if a lookup column in a content type refers to a list, and that list have been removed the lookup will fail.

Comment: I removed the calendar overlays and re-added them. It's working now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the calendar overlays and re-added them. It's working now. Thanks